# Asp.net mvc Web-Api Checking checkbox all for Delete all data showing 500 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to delete all records with checking all checkboxed values. but it is throwing 500 internal server error.

```
//delete all menu
function performalldeletemenu()
{

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this menu?'))
    {
        var AllCheckboxes = new Array();
        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            //console.log($(this).val()); //works fine
            AllCheckboxes .push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/api/MenuWebApi/DeleteAllMenu/',
            data: { deleteservice: AllCheckboxes },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success == true) {
                    GetMenuList();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //window.location = JsErrorAction;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            headers:
            {
                'RequestVerificationToken': JsTokenHeaderValue
            }

        });
    }


    return false;
}
```

### Web-Api Method

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteAllMenu(MenuModel objMenuModel)
        {
}
```

please if any have done before please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ajax request type should be

```
 type: 'Post',
```

2) You Url should be

```
 url: '/api/MenuWebApi/DeleteAllMenu',
```

Comment: For Web -Api if delete method then type will be Delete otherwise it is considering 400 Bad Request. so type will be 'Delete' and URL is correct. i have done so many times with single value and it worked this issue is with  all checkbox values with array.